# MinGW with codeblocks and windows headers

Tags: codeblocks, mingw-w64

I'm using codeblocks with Mingw as my compiler. I'm working on a win32 project (winapi)..
the problem it seems codeblocks does not have access to some windows headers...
in my particular case the header missing is commdlg.h and using a variable in that header the compiler gives me error : the variable was not declared in this scope...

so how do I make codeblocks have all the necessary windows headers using Mingw?
the code is

```
bool Gui::_browseForFile(HWND owner, LPWSTR initialDir, LPWSTR   fileBuffer)
{
OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
Mem::_zero(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAMEW));

ofn.lStructSize     = sizeof(OPENFILENAMEW);
ofn.hwndOwner       = owner;
ofn.lpstrFile       = fileBuffer;
ofn.nMaxFile        = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = initialDir;   
ofn.Flags           = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_ENABLESIZING |  OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;

return CWA(comdlg32, GetOpenFileNameW)(&ofn) ? true : false;
}
```

now the build log is

```
-------------- Build: Debug in NewZe (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++11 -g -masm=intel -g -masm=intel -std=c++11 -g  -c C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp -o obj\Debug\gui.o
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp: In function 'HWND__* Gui::_windowFromPoint(POINT, DWORD, DWORD*)':
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:56:20: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     else if(result == HTTRANSPARENT)
                    ^
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp: In function 'bool Gui::_browseForFile(HWND, LPWSTR, LPWSTR)':
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:146:25: error: 'OFN_DONTADDTORECENT' was not declared in this scope
   ofn.Flags           = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;
                         ^
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp: In function 'bool Gui::_browseForSaveFile(HWND, LPWSTR, LPWSTR, LPWSTR, LPWSTR, DWORD)':
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:163:25: error: 'OFN_DONTADDTORECENT' was not declared in this scope
   ofn.Flags           = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;
                         ^
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp: In function 'bool Gui::_loadCommonControl(DWORD)':
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:182:3: error: 'INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX' was not declared in this scope
   INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX cc;
   ^
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:184:3: error: 'cc' was not declared in this scope
   cc.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
   ^
In file included from C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:8:0:
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\defines.h:3:39: error: '::InitCommonControlsEx' has not been declared
 #define CWA(dll, api)                 ::api
                                       ^
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:187:11: note: in expansion of macro 'CWA'
   return (CWA(Comctl32, InitCommonControlsEx)(&cc) == TRUE);
           ^
C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NewZe\gui.cpp:188:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Comment: How do you know that the header is missing? I ask because have
4 different Windows ports of GCC installed, including MinGW, and all of them have `commdlg.h`.

Comment: so why I'm I getting the error? any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: anyway if it helps, the definition I wanted to use in commdlg.h for which I'm getting a not declared error is #define OFN_DONTADDTORECENT          0x02000000...

Comment: If you're `#include`-ing `commdlg.h` and it is the missing then the compiler says *that it's missing*: `fatal error: no_such_file.h: No such file or directory`. So we've no reason to suppose it's missing. The problem appears to be in your program or your C::B project configuration. Please post 1) the C++ file in which the error arises. 2) the contents of the C::B **Build log** (not the **Build messages**). Copy it with right-mouse **Select all**, CTRL-C and paste it in the body of your question.

Comment: just added the code snippet and the build log..hopefully we find a solution..

Comment: Thanks. No code yet. Can you also post the problem file `gui.cpp`. And,
if `gui.cpp` is *not* the file that contains the program's main function,
then also post the file that contains its main function.

Comment: gui.cpp is a very large one, I posted the place of interest...line 11 in the code snippet

Comment: Sorry that's not enough info. Clearly the cause of the error is not at the
point where it's reported as undeclared but in its declaration having *failed* to emerge from preprocessing at some earlier point. I'm afraid I'll have to drop this if you can't share the relevant code.

Comment: hmm, will just have to resort to using visual studio then, cos with that this error doesn't come up, although I'd prefer to use code blocks..thanks for your time...